# failed to build Mongodb on windows using scons with error saying "The system cannot find the path specified: 'VC\Redist\MSVC'"

Tags: mongodb, scons

Here is the command I executed on windows

```
C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo>scons MONGO_VERSION=4.2.0
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: running with args C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\scons.py MONGO_VERSION=4.2.0
scons version: 3.1.1
python version: 3 8 0 'final' 0
CC is cl
cl was not found in $PATH
cl resolves to C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\cl
CXX is $CC
$CC was not found in $PATH
$CC resolves to C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\$CC
Checking whether the C compiler works... yes
Checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
Checking that the C++ compiler can link a C++ program... yes
Checking if C++ compiler "$CC" is MSVC... yes
Checking if C compiler "cl" is MSVC... yes
Detected a x86_64 processor
Checking if target OS windows is supported by the toolchain... yes
Checking if C compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 15.9 or newer...yes
Checking if C++ compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 15.9 or newer...yes
Checking if we are using libstdc++... no
Checking for C++17... yes
Checking for memset_s... no
Checking for C function strnlen()... yes
Checking Windows SDK is 8.1 or newer... yes
Checking if we are on a POSIX system... no
Checking for storage class thread_local yes
Checking for C++14 std::enable_if_t support...yes
Using SSL Provider: windows
Checking for C++ header file execinfo.h... no
Checking for C library pcap... no
Checking for C library wpcap... no
Checking if std::atomic<int64_t> works... yes
Checking if std::atomic<uint64_t> works... yes
Checking if std::atomic<int32_t> works... yes
Checking if std::atomic<uint32_t> works... yes
Checking for extended alignment 64 for concurrency types... yes
Checking for mongoc_get_major_version() in C library mongoc-1.0... no
Checking for C function fallocate()... no
Checking for C function sync_file_range()... no
Checking for C header file x86intrin.h... no
Checking for C header file arm_neon.h... no
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'VC\\Redist\\MSVC':
  File "C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\SConstruct", line 4255:
    env.SConscript(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 605:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\src\SConscript", line 27:
    env.SConscript('mongo/SConscript', exports=['env'])
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 605:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\src\mongo\SConscript", line 23:
    env.SConscript(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 605:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\src\mongo\installer\SConscript", line 7:
    env.SConscript(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 605:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\scons\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\source\repos\mongo\src\mongo\installer\msi\SConscript", line 59:
```

Comment: There are two things I'd do: The first is to read the build instructions, in particular the requirements and necessary setups. If you followed those on a supported system, then effectively it is a bug in the software you're trying to install. In that case, it's not really a programming question (unless you extract a [mcve] from the sources and intend to fix the bug), so you should rather report this as upstream bug. Speaking of that, go and check existing bugtickets whether one already reported your issue and maybe even provided a fix or workaround.

Comment: I did follow the instruction on how to build mongodb on windows from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source and have all the necessary setup. I think this is likely some issue in that instruction. This is not a mongodb bug. Anyone know the right tag for asking clarifying question on  content from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source

Comment: @Kenneth - This is most likely because `vswhere` is somehow returning an empty string on your system. It would be helpful if you could run a few experiments on your side. In particular, open the file `src\mongo\installer\msi\SConscript`, and add some diagnostic prints around the line that computes `vsinstall_path`. Most likely, something has gone wrong in how that is being computed, which is throwing the subsequent logic off. Interestingly, I happen to be working on refactoring this logic literally today.